# Alert Message displaying in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, message, alert

Is it possible to display consecutive Alert message in j2me... If Yes, could u help me?

i wanna display sms send alert to info the user and after that display the sms receiving alert to the user...

how can it be done?

```
Alert message = new Alert("info");
message.setString("sending");
display.setCurrrent(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, Alert has a timeout. You can make alert visible for the certain amount of time. Use `setTimeout()` for this.

Second, you can always construct other alert and call `display.setCurrrent(message);` again.

Comment: thanx for  the suggestion but if i set the timeout then the midlet exits... so this didnot work in my case..